# Google Workspace SAML login for custom apps

Tags: javascript, saml, google-workspace

Currently at my company we have custom apps to do a bunch of things but each has it's own login and password as well as expiration for passwords and other nonsense. I've been asked to use the SAML that Google Workspace provides to do a SSO button and obtain data to see if the user has an active email. I've been trying to find data for this but it's been very frustrating. Not much about what to do after setting up your application in the admin console for Google Workspace.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en&ref_topic=7559288&sjid=14626356923039703077-SA is the best answer I got.

Does anyone know how I can start creating the login process to obtain the user data?

Comment: So your company is the owner of those custom apps? In that case you have to implement whole SAML SSO flow into those apps. Most of the languages have some kind of libraries to help with that, but it's not going to be easy with multiple apps in multiple stacks.